# What does this Python code do? Explanation of brackets

Tags: python

Can you explain these lines?
I can't understand what's happening in brackets `(j,pbase)`.

```
mults = {}
if c in mults:
    (j,pbase) = mults.pop(c)
```

Comment: What is `c`? You seem to be missing some parts of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpacking a tuple:

```
(j,pbase) = mults.pop(c)
```

Is the same as:

```
x = mults.pop(c)
j = x[0]
pbase = x[1]
```

Comment: can you also explain what happened in this `mults[m] = (j,pbase)`?

Comment: Dictionary key `m` is assigned to the tuple `(j,pbase)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a,b = something
```

This means `something` is a sequence of two values.  `a` is assigned to the first value, and `b` is assigned to the second.

This is called *tuple unpacking*.

Answer (score 0):

the python `.pop()` function will remove the item at that index and then return whatever was deleted. this means that the element of `mults` at index `c` will be stored within `j` and `pbase`. the way this is written would suggest that each element of the list is a tuple or such. this would mean that the first item goes in `j` and the second in `pbase`.